# How can I remove elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I am working on a multipage paint like application, there is a 'clear' button. When the user presses that, I want all the shapes drawn on that page to be cleared. Following is the code behind clear button.

```
clear.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        canvas.width = canvas.width;
        tempCanvas.width = tempCanvas.width;
        var tempShapes = shapes.slice();
        alert(tempShapes.length);
        for(var i=0; i<tempShapes.length; i++)
        {

            var A = tempShapes[i];
            if(A.pageNum == pNum)
            {
                alert('in');
                shapes.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        //shapes.length = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

`shapes[]` is the array holding complete objects of all pages. I just want to remove the ones with the current pagenumber (`pNum`). When the code runs, it leaves one element in the shape array for that particular page and sometimes two elements. I want all the elements of shape array for that particular page removed.

Comment: Ideally? Use `jQuery.filter` or `_.filter` or an `Array.filter` polyfill. This is why these utility libraries are so ubiquitous in the JavaScript world...

Comment: @meagar `Array.filter` is native javascript, no need for libraries.

Comment: If you don't want to use Array.filter, then iterating backwards (for var i = tempShapes.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {}) will allow you to splice safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) more useful for this task, something like:

```
shapes = shapes.filter(function(shape, i) {
    return tempShapes[i].pageNum != pnum;
})
```

Comment: shapes.splice(i--, 1) makes it stuck in an infinite loop.. can you kindly explain how can i use Array.filter in my case?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar, he is practically giving you the code. What can't you understand.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your array indexes are not in sync after you remove the first element:

```
orig : 0-0, 1-1, 2-2 
temp : 0-0, 1-1, 2-2

remove orig[0] -> index 0 -> temp[0] = 0

orig : 0-0, 1-1, 2-2 
temp : 0-1, 1-2

remove orig[1] -> index 1 -> temp[1] = 2 !!
```

You can remove from the same array you are iterating over:

```
clear.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    for(var i=shapes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if(shapes[i].pageNum == pNum) {
            shapes.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Or you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them:

```
clear.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    shapes = shapes.filter(function(item) { return item.pageNum != pNum });
    e.preventDefault();
}
```